# How to remove top space within a div tag

Tags: css, margin, padding

I am placing a header text in a division. Fortunately i am getting unwanted space above that text. When i am trying to increasing the size of the text, the text is moving downwards. So here, I want to increase my text size and at the same time i want to move it upwards of division. Is it possible to remove the top space and move it upwards ?

I have tried padding-top: in negative pixels. But that didn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="stylish">
    <h1> keep you stylish </h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.stylish{
    font-family:"Brush Script MT", cursive;
    font-size:1.3em;
}
```

Comment: I have tried padding-top: in negative pixels. But that didn't work.

Comment: set line-height: value;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not the `div`, it's the `<h1>` tag. Try this:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Your can also try:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a css reset in the inception of every css:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

[Source](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 1):

```
h1
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

or you may try this too

```
h1
{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;//top left bottom right
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

and .stylish must have padding:0px;  i.e;

```
.stylish
{
padding:0px;
}
```

**Reason:**

By default each tag like `<H1>,<P>`... Comes with minimum margin and padding So in order to reduce that gaps we need to give margin=0px;padding =0px externally

More about margin and padding refer

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/

http://webdesign.about.com/od/faqsandhelp/f/bl_faq5_7a.htm

http://html.net/tutorials/css/lesson10.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.stylish
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

you may require to set margin and padding to zero for its parent element too, if it doesn't work

But for u the white space is the margin of div's parent..

so set the parents margin to 0px;

Comment: Try setting the background-color for the stylish div and find where the gap appears

Comment: *
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
This will work clearly for you.. But its just enough to give this style to the parent node.

Comment: Thank you for your time bro., I applied the same changes you suggested to the h1 tag., then it's working. :)